# How to add connector c++ and boost to clion project on windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm setting up a new server for a c++ application and i need to interact with a DB. I need to include connector c++ and boost to my project but this doesn't work.

Boost is extracted in: `C:\boost_1_71_0`

Mysql connector is installed in: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 8.0`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(shared-editor-server)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64/vs14)
set(
        SOURCE_FILES

        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/*.h
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn/*.h
        ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64/vs14
)



add_executable(shared-editor-server ${SOURCE_FILES} main.cpp connectDB.cpp server.cpp server.h connectDB.h)
```

The `#include "mysql_driver.h"` says that the file is not found. The same for other `.h` files.

Answer (score 1):

Your path to the MySQL connector contains spaces, so when you define the variable, enclose the path with quotes:

```
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0")
```

Also, because you have used the `include_directories()` calls, including the headers with `SOURCE_FILES` appears redundant. If you are trying to pull these headers into an IDE, say CLion, it is best to list each header individually (as you have done with the `.cpp` files). Listing the headers as `*.h` in the `set` call will not work.

---

Based on your feedback, I have a few suggestions for further adjusting the CMake file:

1. You set the C++ standard to C++17 with `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, then immediately try setting it to C++11, with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. These are contradictory, so only choose one.
2. The files provided to `add_executable()` only need to be the source (`.cpp`) files. The headers will be included via your other CMake calls.
3. Use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) instead of `include_directories()` to apply the included directories only to a **specific** target, not **all** targets. This way, other targets handled by your CMake don't get over-crowded with includes.
4. If you want to link the MySQL Connector library to your executable, use [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) to provide the path to the library you wish to link to.

Putting this together, you get something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(shared-editor-server)
# Choose only one of these standards.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0")

# You only really need to include your source files here.
add_executable(shared-editor-server 
    main.cpp 
    connectDB.cpp 
    server.cpp
)

# Add the MySQL include directories to this target.
target_include_directories(shared-editor-server PRIVATE 
    ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc
)
target_include_directories(shared-editor-server PRIVATE 
    ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/jdbc/cppconn
)

# Link the MySQL library to your executable.
target_link_libraries(shared-editor-server PRIVATE 
    ${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib64/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib
)
```

Comment: "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: shared-editor-server" This is the output after i insert quotes in the path. The folder include contains only folders.

Comment: @ReddaHawk I've expanded my answer to account for some other potential issues I saw in your CMake file.

Answer (score 1):

If c++ mysql connector doesn't work for you, I suggest to read more about connector - compiler dependency.

[> the code that uses Connector/C++ libraries should be built with the same compiler version as the connector itself. The information about compiler version used to build connector libraries can be found inside INFO_BIN file distributed with the connector.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/usage.html)

I had issues in cLion just cuz of compiler, I've changed cLion on VS and it solved my problem.

Comment: I think it too but i wasn't sure. Thank you