# How to run MySQL/C++ Connector in CLion

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, cmake, clion

I want to run **MySQL/C++ Connector** in CLion IDE.

I befor ran it in Visual Studio 2019 and it worked. I know that how to define **MySQL/C++ Connector** libraries in visual studio project but i dont know how to this in CLion.

So ***how to run MySQL/C++ Connector in CLion***, *i mean how to declare MySQL/C++ Connector libraries and dll files in CLion.*

Comment: There are plenty questions about using MySQL C++ Connector with Clion/CMake. Have you checked them? E.g. this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187088/how-to-add-connector-c-and-boost-to-clion-project-on-windows-10.

Comment: my mysql connector libs builded in vs14 and i use vs17, does it makes problem?

Comment: Since you don't describe your attempt, it is hard to say whether a some thing could be a problem or not. But generally, yes, libraries created by **different** Visual Studio versions are **incompatible**. Please, read [ask] and update your question according to that guide.